# postfix quota postmaster daily mail

Tags: postfix, quota, courier

I've got an server with Postfix/Courier and Quota. Now I receive a daily update from quota.

2 questions:

1. Where do I disable this daily update as it's always a blank email:

   ```
    DAILY QUOTA REPORT:

   ----------------------------------------------
   | % USAGE |            ACCOUNT NAME          |
   ----------------------------------------------
   ```
2. Where can i change the from / to fields from this quota mail.

PS. I'm running an Ubuntu server

Comment: `I've got an server with Postfix/Courier and Quota` ---> So, did you inherit legacy server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Looks like* the quota report produced by `/usr/local/sbin/quota_notify`. I'm tracked the same email format from this article [Virtual Users And Domains With Postfix, Courier, MySQL And SquirrelMail (Ubuntu 14.04LTS)](https://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-ubuntu-14.04-lts-p3) **step 11**. The user script was written in perl and contains some explanation about the parameters.

*If the script doesn't match the description above: (1) check your crontab entry, (2) post full email source at your question*

Comment: thanks.. that was it. changed `my $MAIL_REPORT = 0;` and it looks good now.